# save XSL output to XML with PHP

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I have the following PHP code. The XSL transformation works fine, and echoes a string fine to the server, but when I try to save, I get "Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::save()"  Using PHP 5.3
Simple problem?

```
<?php


$xml = new DOMDocument;
$xml->load('myxml.xml');

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load('myxsl.xsl');

$proc = new XSLTProcessor();
$proc->importStylesheet($xsl);
$newXml = $proc->transformToXML($xml);
$newXML->formatOutput=true;
echo $newXml;

$newXML->save("newfile.xml")or die("Error");
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[transformToXML()](http://php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.transformtoxml.php) returns a *string*. You can of course use `file_put_contents()` to store that string in a file, you can however do it directly with:

```
 $proc->transformToURI($xml,'file://'.getcwd().'/newfile.xml');
```

.. or any other directory then the current working dir (*=`getcwd()`*).

If you want to set some properties / do some tinkering before saving, you might want to:

```
$newDOM = $proc->transformToDoc($xml);
$newDOM->formatOutput = true;
$newDOM->save("newfile.xml")
```